# Should I use Material-UI for big enterprise application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, single-page-application

We are migrating big and ugly MVC based Java EE application to React. The application in question is a browser based UI with hundreds of views featuring complex forms, listings and links. It's intended for officer desktop use, so responsiveness is not a concern.

I have built some small admin dashboards with React without using component library, which was hard enough by it's own right. Considering the huge size of this project and amount of developers working on it, I'm considering utilizing a component library for a solid base. I'm seeking for a *framework* containing the UI components, layout utilities, error handling, validation support etc. Of course the look and feel should be customizable.

Is the Material-UI library a good choice in this case? Do you recommend some additional libraries with it to streamline the development?

Comment: ReactJS is not a framework, is just a javascript library for the "View" part of the project, the "model" and the "controller" part must be done by yourself.

Of course you can have some plugin to help you handle this. 

If you are looking for a Framework i suggest to look at [angular.io](https://angular.io/) that is actually a framework, with: components, layout, error handling, validation, interceptors and so on.

Comment: To second @Margon I want to add that it seems that Material Design is easy to integrate with angular.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, material-ui is a fine choice. It is widely used and very customizable. In my company we are using it for all our frontend projects.

As @Margon already mentioned React is only a library and you probably want to add some additional libraries. The most important are in my opinion `react-router` for routing and you will want some kind of state management. The most popular are `redux` and `mobx`.